# Copying multiple files by *.extension with xcopy

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I'm making a batch script to copy all `.doc`, `.pdf`, `.xls` etc from disk to a pendrive.

My current code below:

```
@echo off
Title ""

::All Docs
 XCOPY C:\*.doc W:\xdatabase /C /S /I /F /H > W:\database\XC\AllInf.txt

::All PDFs
 XCOPY C:\*.pdf W:\xdatabase /C /S /I /F /H >> W:\database\XC\AllInf.txt

::All WRI
 XCOPY C:\*.wri W:\xdatabase /C /S /I /F /H >> W:\database\XC\AllInf.txt

::All TXT
 XCOPY C:\*.txt W:\xdatabase /C /S /I /F /H >> W:\database\XC\AllInf.txt

::All PPT
 XCOPY C:\*.ppt W:\xdatabase /C /S /I /F /H >> W:\database\XC\AllInf.txt

::All XLS
 XCOPY C:\*.xls W:\xdatabase /C /S /I /F /H >> W:\database\XC\AllInf.txt
```

The question is: How can I add more extensions but avoid all that duplication in the code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Always true, in all programming languages: If you have to do a thing multiple times in a row, use a loop.

```
@echo off
Title ""

for %%e in (doc pdf wri txt ppt xls) do (
    XCOPY "C:\*.%%e" W:\xdatabase /C /S /I /F /H > W:\database\XC\AllInf.txt
)
```

The `for` loop can be tricky in batch scripting. A handy guide is here: http://ss64.com/nt/for.html

Comment: Oh, im grateful, that exacly what I was asking thks a lot

Comment: @Derley You can also check out robocopy for ways to include multiple sources in one single command.

Comment: @Tomalak This for loop can't be done in one statement?

Comment: @johny I don't think so. `xcopy` only accepts only one source argument.

Comment: @Tomalak This works on one line: `for %f in (xlsm xlsb) do xcopy SourceDir\*.%f DestinationDir\ /S`

Comment: @johnywhy That's a loop, too. That you wrote it on one line makes no difference.

Comment: @Tomalak True, i never said it wasn't a loop.

Comment: @johnywhy It's also not one statement. But we really don't need to argue about this. Your and my approach are equivalent. Mine is formatted to be used in a batch file, yours is formatted as a one-off command. They're still the same thing. Use whatever is more convenient in any given situation.

Comment: @Tomalak It's my confusion about the difference between "one statement" vs "one command". Anyway, now i'm playing with robocopy.

Answer (score 2):

This works on one line, no script-file needed. Needs single percent-sign, not double:

```
for %f in (xlsm xlsb) do xcopy SourceDir\*.%f DestinationDir\ /S
```

or in your case

```
for %e in (doc pdf xls wri txt ppt xls) do XCOPY C:\*.%e W:\xdatabase /C /S /I /F /H > W:\database\XC\AllInf.txt
```

according to my tests, [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) supports multiple extensions without a loop.

```
ROBOCOPY C:\ W:\xdatabase /S *.doc *.pdf *.xls *.wri *.txt *.ppt *.xls
```

However, in my experience xcopy seems to beat robocopy on [speed](https://www.flexense.com/robocopy_vs_xcopy_file_copy_performance.html), even with multiple extensions, but i only tested with a very small batch of files.

Comment: +1 for including robocopy, which helped me as it's clearly an XY question and robocopy's a better fit than xcopy for multiple extensions.