# Searching and Copying Files

Tags: file, search, copying

**The main objective is to Search the System for files and then copy them without using File Transfer Protocol (FTP)**

Need help building a program that searches the System [Windows] for all files with .docx, .doc & .pdf files and then copies them to another directory.
One of my colleagues sent me this code:

[scan a directory to find files in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149569/scan-a-directory-to-find-files-in-c)

This code searches for the files, how to I copy them to a specific directory?

Best regards,
CarlosG

Comment: This feels more like a request on a gig site than a question about code you have written that you need help with. i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1224880/125981 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/39451898/125981  or  https://stackoverflow.com/q/40573876/125981.  Questions such as do you wish to maintain sub folder structure, what do do when duplicate file names exist etc remain.  Much too broad here.

Comment: Yeah, you're right! I'll be more careful next time, thank you very much!